# taylor expansion for $\frac1{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a closed expression for the taylor series of $\frac1{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$ in a neighborhood of $x = 0$. One can obtain the coefficients from: $$(a_o+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)(1-x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}--++\cdots) = 1$$
thus $a_0= 1, a_1=1, a_2 = 3/2$, etc. Is it possible to find a recursive or symbolic law (like $(B+1)^n-B^n = 0$ for bernoulli numbers) for the coefficients $a_n$?

**edit:** if we let $a_n = b_n/n!$, we can find the following: $$b_n = \binom{n}1b_{n-1}+\binom{n}2b_{n-2}-\binom{n}3b_{n-3}-\binom{n}4b_{n-4}++--\cdots$$ for $n\ge1$, and $b_0 = 1$. Still this is not very appealing.

Comment: I don't know if it might help but $\frac{1}{\cos x-\sin x} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sec(x+\pi/4)$ so you're basically looking for the coefficients of the expansion of $\sec$ around $-\pi/4$.

Comment: @ECL. Why around $-\frac \pi 4$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients of numerators are
$$\{1,1,3,11,19,361,307,24611,83579,2873041,12193841,512343611,869783713\}$$ and for denominators
$$\{1,1,2,6,8,120,80,5040,13440,362880,1209600,39916800,53222400\}$$ You could find them in $OEIS$ (sequences $A279257$ and $A279258$) but according to the pages, they do not show any particularity.

**Edit**

If it was around $x=-\frac \pi 4$ (which is not the case)
$$\sec \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{E_{2 n}}{(2 n)!}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^{2 n}$$ where appear Euler numbers.